# Windows VirtualBox failed to attach USB device to Linux Guest

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, arch-linux

I have Windows 7 64bit Host system, and I am using VirtualBox 4.1.18 (r78361).

I have an Arch Linux Guest OS.

I have installed VirtualBox Extension Pack (to enable USB2 support) and added my USB device filter to VM.
I have also installed the Guest Additions provided by Arch: `virtualbox-archlinux-additions` (but I have no idea whether it's actually needed for my environment).

I can see my USB device from VirtualBox Devices menu.

Whenever I am trying to access it, I end up with:

> Failed to attach the USB device **Kingston DT 100 G2 [0100]** to the
>   virtual machine **Archlinux**.
>
> USB device '**Kingston DT 100 G2**' with UUID
>   *{a836ec33-0f41-4ca7-a31d-09cceaf5d173}* is busy with a previous request. Please try again later.
>
> Details `↓`
>   `Result Code:    E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)`
>   `Component:      HostUSBDevice`
>   `Interface:      IHostUSBDevice {173b4b44-d268-4334-a00d-b6521c9a740a}`
>   `Callee:         IConsole {1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}`

From what I have googled, most guides shows how to solve this the other way around - Linux Host to Windows Guest.

How do I resolve this?

#### Update

I have tried to Eject (virtually, not physically) the device from my Windows Host system and then try to access the Device from Guest. Same error.

Comment: Similar question with answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/461406/windows-virtualbox-failed-to-attach-usb-device-to-linux-guest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like VBox has some problems with USB3 hubs, and so, plugging my USB key into an USB2 slot did everything. See [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/3033#comment:30).

Comment: I don't have USB2 slots... :(

Comment: Same issue/state (USB 2.0 ports only work) several years later - in 2021, VirtualBox 6.1.26. And the situation seems to be the same from Linux host.
  The logged-in host OS user is member of vboxusers as mentioned in other questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is years old and there is still a problem with USB 3.0 in VirtualBox.

I'm running an up-to-date Ubuntu 20.04 host, Virtualbox 6.1.10_Ubuntu r138449 (most recent in Ubuntu repos) with a Windows 7 guest. My computer only has USB 3.0 ports. My external USB 3.0 hard drive fails to attach to the guest.

In my urgent case, I plugged a USB 2.0 hub into the computer, and the USB 3.0 HDD into that hub. It works, but at USB 2.0 speeds :)

Also, with any Linux host, make sure the user running VirtualBox is in the "vboxusers" group.